# how to efficiently find indexes for alternating booleans in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, logic, dataframe

With a dataframe like one shown below:

```
       A      B  
0   True  False  
1   True  False  
2   True  False  
3  False   True  
4  False  False  
5   True  False
```

I need to get a list of the indexes for alternating booleans between column a and b. So the first time column A shows True, I can add 0 to the list. Now I switch to column B and find the next index after 0 that shows True which is 3. Then I switch back to column A to add the next index to show True after index 3. In the end I will have a list with the values [0, 3, 5]. I'm currently building these lists by iterating through the rows in a for loop and with if statements. I don't think this is the most efficient way this can be done. Any help on the "correct" way to do this will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way could be something like this:

In [3]:

```
df['C'] = df.A.astype(int) - df.B.astype(int)
df['D'] = df[['C']].apply(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).astype(int).cumsum())
df[(df.C == 1) | (df.C == -1)].groupby('D').head(1).index
```

Out[3]:

```
Int64Index([0, 3, 5], dtype='int64')
```

I haven't tested it extensively, but it works with the samples you provided, including this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True, True, False, True, False, False, True], 
                   'B': [False, False, True, False, False, True, False]})
```

In [4]:

```
df['C'] = df.A.astype(int) - df.B.astype(int)
df['D'] = df[['C']].apply(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).astype(int).cumsum())
df[(df.C == 1) | (df.C == -1)].groupby('D').head(1).index.tolist()
```

Out[4]:

```
[0, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Primer. I've never worked with groupby before so I'm having a hard time understanding how it works. Especially when its groupby more than one column. I tested your code with a different dataframe and it didn't give me what I expected.

A = [True, True, False, True, False, False, True]  
B = [False, False, True, False, False, True, False]  
got [0, 2, 5] instead of [0, 2, 3, 5, 6]

Comment: It is difficult to overestimate importance of `.groupby` operations, so I would encourage you to see examples in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) or here in the forum. The best way to understand the code is to break it down and see what it does.     I have updated the code to take this new cases into account. I am quite sure it will work fine now in all cases. And it since you didn't mention it anywhere it will ignore lines where `A` and `B` are both `True`. But you can change it in line 3 of the code setting condition to `df.C != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this better?

```
inputList=[(True,False),(True,False),(True,False),
          (False,True),(False,False),(True,False)]
l=list()
toggle=0

for i in range(0,len(inputList)):
    if (inputList[i][toggle%2]==True):
        l.append(i)
        toggle+=1
print l
```

Comment: Feel free if you need any comment.